# How to overcome breaking API change in com.nimbusds version 4.14?

Tags: java, servlets, oauth, openid

We have Oauth2 server implementation build on [Nimbus OAuth 2.0 SDK](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk).

Now we are using **version 4.13** *(com.nimbusds - oauth2-oidc-sdk)* but want to upgrade to the latest **version 5.13** - *for no particular reason just want to have latest before release.*

We are using java servlets for implementing OAuth endpoints and often we are using:

```
com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPResponse.applyTo(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse sr)
```

but function `applyTo(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse sr)` not exists in the API any more. (It was remove between versions 4.13 and 4.14)

I have google that for some time and also tried to find some other way how to get (or modify existing) `HttpServletResponse` from the `com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPResponse`.

*I suggest that there should be some work around like http response writer or something so but I am loosing it completly.*

Did someone overcome this api change?

If so thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't quite follow.  The method you reference does not provide a means to "get an `HttpServletResponse` from the `com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPResponse`."  Rather, supposing that you already have the `HttpServletResponse` in hand, that method modifies it.

Comment: Yes you are right but nevertheless it does not contains any method working with HttpServletResponse any more. Of course I have HttpServletResponse in hand in servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for 
[`com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.ServletUtils.applyHTTPResponse()`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/5.13/com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/http/ServletUtils.html#applyHTTPResponse-com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPResponse-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-).  Evidently, Nimbus has been refactored so that `HttpResponse` is a data-only class, not a behavioral class.  Its one behavioral method was moved to `ServletUtils`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. ServletUtils was the right way to check.